# How can i connect redux with localStorage so that when updating the like on the page does not disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can i connect redux with localStorage so that when updating the like on the page does not disappear

i have redux.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import favouriteReducer from "./reducers/favouriteReducer";

const redusers = combineReducers({
    favourite: favouriteReducer,
});

const store = createStore(redusers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    items: []
}

function favouriteReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_MOVIE':
            return {
                items: state.items.concat(action.payload)
            }
        case 'REMOVE_MOVIE':
            return {
                items: state.items.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default favouriteReducer;
```

action.js

```
export function addMovie(id) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_MOVIE',
        payload: id
    }
}

export function removeMovie(id) {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_MOVIE',
        payload: id
    }
}
```

and component where i add to redux my movie on click on svg

```
import React from "react";
import './index.css';
import { Link} from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addMovie, removeMovie } from "../../../../redux/actions/favouriteMovie";

const Movie = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const active = useSelector((store) => store.favourite.items.find(item => item === props.id));

  let onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addMovie(props.id))
    localStorage.setItem('active', active)


    if (active) {
      dispatch(removeMovie(props.id))
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <Link to= {"/modal/:"+`${props.id}`} id={props.id} className={'movie'}>
        <img src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+props.poster_path} alt={props.title} className={'main'}/>
        <h1 className={'title'}>{props.title}</h1>
        <div>
            <svg className={active ? 'activeimg' : 'heart'}  onClick={onClick} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"/></svg>
        <p className={'text'}>{props.release_date}</p>
        </div>
    </Link>
  );

};

export default Movie;
```

I can't understand how to connect this redux with localStorage. how can i get items from localStorage in redux when updating. Now i get undefined on click and red svg, then one more time click and i receive id this movie in localStorage and white svg, but need red.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where you trying to get item from localstorage  write this line```localStorage.getItem('active')```. If you share your code somewhere like codesandbox etc so there I can update it to show you

Comment: You should probably not do that by hand, but just use an established library like https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

**redux.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import favouriteReducer from "./reducers/favouriteReducer";

const redusers = combineReducers({
    favourite: favouriteReducer,
});

function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error occured ', err)
    }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serializedState === null) return undefined;
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error occured ', err)
    }
}

const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

const store = createStore(redusers, persistedState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()))

export default store;
```